# How lock fancybox overlay without jumping to the top?

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox-2

I want to disable browser scrolling when fancybox opened. And next code works:

```
helpers: {
   overlay: {
      locked: true 
   }
},
```

But on mobile devices window jump to top during fancybox opening. This behavior depends at locked: true param. How can I lock overlay and prevent jumping?

Different decisions, such as:

```
$('html').css('overflow', 'hidden')
```

or

```
$(document.body).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.returnValue = false;
});
```

Works, but not in all mobile browsers!

Comment: If you are using fancybox v2.1.5 it seems that the issue has been fixed in the latest master that you can download form here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip

Comment: version: 2.1.5 (Fri, 14 Jun 2013). This issue hasn't been fixed. (

Comment: As far as I can see, the master update is from Oct 09, 2013

Comment: I have downloaded last version, but bug is present.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue but in iOS safari, there's always a certain amount of rubber band scrolling when you move your finger. If Safari's, bottom nav is visbile when you scroll, it dissappears but leaves a gap and you can see and scroll the content underneath through this gap. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I also had to deal with this issue and it has driven me mad. I tried nearly all options, searched all questions and answers on stackoverflow but nothing seemed to work with my ajax-lightbox. I always jumped to the top. Then I did the following:

```
$(".lightboxe-fancyboxWindow").fancybox({ 
    type : 'ajax',
    href : "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        data: {     
            'data1' : information1,
            'data2' : information2
        },
    },
    autoSize: false,
    width: '60%',
    beforeShow : function() {
        $("body").css({"overflow" : "hidden", "padding-right" : "17px"});
    },
    afterClose: function () {
        $("html, body").removeAttr("style");
    },
    titleShow : false,
    helpers : { 
        overlay : {
            locked : false
        },
         title : null
    },
});
```

What I did was to add overflow hidden on body tag and `17px` padding for the `fake-scrollbar`.